# Have any techniques from Yii 1 to Yii2 Upgrade

Tags: regex, netbeans, yii, yii2

For Yii2 upgrade from Yii1, some of syntax i think can replace from regex.

Such as

1. Yii::app() ===> \Yii::$app->
2. array(.*)  ===> [.....]

I'm using netbeans IDE, Can anyone suggest for above two syntax regular expression ?

else have any techniques ;-)

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2):

Upgrade from Yii1 to Yii2,Some of my simple tricks Search & Replace for in my Netbeans IDE,

```
Yii::app()->           =>    \Yii::$app->

$this->render(         =>    return $this->render(

$this->redirect(       =>    return $this->redirect(

->user->setFlash(      =>    ->getSession()->setFlash(

->user->getState('     =>    ->session->get('

::model()->findByPk(   =>    ::findOne(
```

So i need a regular expression for a string contains like from 
 
array(.....blah..blah.....) ==>change to==> [...blah...blah...]

Answer (score 0):

This links shows some of the differences
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-intro-upgrade-from-v1.html
you do not have to change the array by the way. You can but it is not necessary. You have to change the models too as they are using the find() function instead of model() (but i am not sure about this one).

There are too many changes I do not believe you can get a lot done with search and replace.